# Failed to find data source: kafka. using Docker all-spark-notebook Spark Ver 3.1.1

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, jupyter

I'm very new to Spark and Kafka and I'm trying to run some sample code in Python (Jupyter) using Docker images downloaded, configured and executed with docker-compose.  I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 through Windows 10 WSL.

Here are the steps I've followed so far:

1. Using the docker-compose.yml file shown below, I run [docker-compose up -d]
2. All containers start successfully
3. I start a Jupyter notebook using http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=
4. I execute the Python script line-by-line and it fails at

   ````
       .readStream \
       .format("kafka") \
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
       .option("subscribe", "cloud") \
       .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
       .load()```
   ````

with the error:

`error preamble... AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".`

I'm clearly missing a step and I've searched in-vain for a solution.  Other answers to this problem suggest adding:

`import os os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1 pyspark-shell'`

which hasn't worked for me.  What step am I missing?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  spark:
    image: jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    working_dir: /home/$USER/work
    volumes:
      - $PWD/work:/home/$USER/work

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Dzookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist=*"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/data/connect-jars
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.kafka.connect=DEBUG
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
        cd /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/lib
        curl http://repo.odysseusinc.com/artifactory/community-libs-release-local/org/netezza/nzjdbc/1.0/nzjdbc-1.0.jar -o nzjdbc-1.0.jar
        /etc/confluent/docker/run &
        sleep infinity
```

**Python Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1 pyspark-shell'


# In[ ]:


#    Spark
import pyspark
import findspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
#    Spark Streaming
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
#    json parsing
import json


# In[ ]:


findspark.init()


# In[ ]:


spark = SparkSession     .builder     .appName("My App")     .getOrCreate()
#    .config("spark.jars", "/path/to/jar.jar,/path/to/another/jar.jar") \


# In[ ]:


spark.version


# In[ ]:


df = spark         .readStream         .format("kafka")         .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")         .option("subscribe", "cloud")         .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")         .load()
```

Comment: You could try adding `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` to the compose file env, otherwise, yeah, that's the correct solution (although localhost is not the correct Kafka address), however, you might want to verify that you're using the correct version of scala and spark for the package. You can also download and mount the jar into the container, like you've commented out

Comment: @OneCricketeer Quick question then (from a total noob): the package org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1, should that be supplied as part of the spark image.  I mean, setting the environment variable just tells spark where to find the library, right?  I've pulled the latest images, but is it possible the library (as specified) isn't actually there?

Comment: Kafka "plugin" for structured streaming doesn't come with Spark, no. The variable injects dependency definitions, yes. You can use maven central to find what packages exist. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.1.1